# How to include multiple function calls or assignments in an if-then statement

Tags: xquery

I am new to xquery and have a hard time finding more than just the basics online. I have existing code I want to change but I don't know how to include multiple function calls or variable assignments in a single if-then statement.

Say I have this block

```
if (fn:namespace-uri(.) = 'http://xmlns.oracle.com/communications/sce/dictionary/testNamespace' 
and //tns:CreateSalesOrder/tns:ListOfSWIOrderIO/tns:SWIOrder/tns:OrderTypeCode/text() = 'Test Order'
and $isDefaultVersion)
    then true()
else false()
```

How can I include a function call after true()?

Something like this but I dont know the exact syntax:

```
 if (fn:namespace-uri(.) = 'http://xmlns.oracle.com/communications/sce/dictionary/testNamespace' 
and //tns:CreateSalesOrder/tns:ListOfSWIOrderIO/tns:SWIOrder/tns:OrderTypeCode/text() = 'Test Order'
and $isDefaultVersion)
    then true(), util:write-record('123','johndoe')
else false()
```

Comment: `if` is an expression, not a statement. If you want the `then` to return a sequence of the `true()` value and the result of the function call then construct a sequence with e.g. `(true(), util:write-record('123','johndoe'))`. Whether that makes sense is not clear, it depends on what kind of expression you want to return.

Answer (score 1):

You can write:

```
if (...) then (true(), util:write-record('123','johndoe')) else ...
```

Note the parentheses.

I suspect from the name that `util:write-record()` is a function that has side-effects. Functions with side-effects are very tricky in XQuery and you need to understand how they are handled by your particular implementation. There is always a risk that the query optimizer will change the order of evaluation so side-effects happen in an unexpected order, or that particular calls will not happen at all because the optimizer decides the result is not needed.